# Python Script pipe ">" not writing to file

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, logging

I'm developing a script in python.

So far the call from OS with pipe > was working and writting all my print messages to text file.

Now, no matter how I execute it. the log file is always empty:

`PS C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Proyectos\Bot> python .\bot.py > "log$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyy_HH-mm).txt"`

If i execute the code normally, messages are shown on the terminal, but im unable to redirect them to the file:

```
2023-03-07 17:28:49.469679 -Se buscará en el path /group/canal-online/catalogo-general 
2023-03-07 17:28:49.470677 -Se buscará en el path /group/canal-online/catalogo-general
2023-03-07 17:28:49.470677 -Se buscará en el path /group/canal-online/todos-los-catalogos
2023-03-07 17:28:49.470677 -Se buscará en el path /group/canal-online/carrito
EXCEL LOADED
LOGIN INTO PAGE
COOKIES OBTAINED
STARTING...
```

Not sure but my previous version was working... something in the code made it stop...

Some print examples:

```
print(str(datetime.now()) + " -COMIENZA LA EJECUCION")
print(str(datetime.now()) + " -DICCIONARIO DE BUSQUEDA: " + str(faltasCodigoDict))
print(str(datetime.now()) + " -Buscando Codigos Internos en Web... Response Code: " + str(respuestaCatalogo.status_code))
print(str(datetime.now()) + " -Tamaño JSON: " + str(len(respuestaCatalogo.content.decode("utf-8"))))
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks in advance.

I changed the OS call for including stderr and sdout with 1 and 2 but it did not work.

Also tried Out-File powershell cmdlet and still nothing:

```
python .\bot.py | out-file "log$(get-date -f dd-MM-yyy_HH-mm).txt"
```

[image: Log Empty]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work adding flush to empty the buffer on each print.

```
flush=True
```

Question still there... Why this was working before and suddenly I need this?
Output was streaming "live" to the file a few hours back...

BR